# Why doesn't this pattern matching work as expected in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to replicate the powerful pattern matching example that Joshua Suereth presented in his Devoxx 2013 talk titled "How to wield Scala in the trenches". Unfortunately I cannot achieve what he described and I cannot understand what is wrong. Can someone give me a hint at what I'm missing? (My Scala version is 2.10.3)

Please see the self contained code below:

```
case class Person(name: String, residence: Seq[Residence])
case class Residence(city: String, country: String)

object LivesIn {
  def unapply(p: Person): Option[Seq[String]] =
    Some(
      for(r <- p.residence)
      yield r.city
    )
}

class StringSeqContains(value: String) {
  def unapply(in: Seq[String]): Boolean =
    in contains value
}

object PatternPower extends App {

  val people =
    Seq(Person("Emre", Seq(Residence("Antwerp", "BE"))),
      Person("Ergin", Seq(Residence("Istanbul", "TR"))))

  val Istanbul = new StringSeqContains("Istanbul")

  // #1 does not work as expected, WHY?
  println(
    people collect {
      case person @ LivesIn(Istanbul) => person
    }
  )

  // #2 works as expected
  println(
    people collect {
      case person @ LivesIn(cities) if cities.contains("Istanbul") => person
    }
  )

  // #3 works as expected
  println(
    people collect {
      case person @ Person(_, res) if res.contains(Residence("Istanbul", "TR")) => person
    }
  )

}
```

When I compile and run it I get:

```
List()
List(Person(Ergin,List(Residence(Istanbul,TR))))
List(Person(Ergin,List(Residence(Istanbul,TR))))
```

As denoted in the source code, I fail to grasp why the first pattern does not produce the same result as the remaining two pattern matches. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking and Googling, I realized that one should add `()` to the inner extractor (thanks to [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 1: Extractors](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html)).

In other words, the following works as expected:

```
people collect {
  case person @ LivesIn(Istanbul()) => person
}
```

whereas the following code silently, without any complaints, returns `List()`:

```
people collect {
  case person @ LivesIn(Istanbul) => person
}
```

Unless I'm mistaken in another way (e.g. there is way to make it work without parantheses), I think technical presenters should be more careful with the code snippets / pseudo-code snippets (so that some of the curious audience will not lose sleepless hours ;-)

Comment: you might want to fill a bug report about this.

Comment: not sure if this is a bug, let me check with people on [scala-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-user).

Comment: It's not a bug. Without the parentheses the match criteria is equality with the stable value that is the referent of specified name.

Comment: Not a bug indeed. Nevertheless, I think it is fair enough to categorize this as a pitfall.

Comment: Due to unsatisfactory answers in scala-users, I moved the question to the scala-internals list and got some solid [answers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/Er3wNj6gLcU).

Answer (score 6):

Your LivesIn extractor requires a Seq for an argument.

The following variation does what you expect:

```
println(
  people collect {
    case person @ LivesIn(List("Istanbul")) => person
  }
)
```

Comment: Your example works, but it does not solve the mystery for me, because I'm trying to understand why ```LivesIn(Istanbul)``` does not work where ```Istanbul``` is defined as ```val Istanbul = new StringSeqContains("Istanbul")```.

Comment: The pattern target constraint you supplied is incompatible with the extractor.

Comment: Still trying to understand, e.g. the following code ```List(List("Istanbul")) collect {case city if Istanbul.unapply(city) => city}``` returns ```List(List(Istanbul))```. I really fail to understand why the value ```Istanbul``` defined as ```new StringSeqContains("Istanbul")``` cannot be used as ```LivesIn(Istanbul)``` to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Look at the return type for the extractor (`unapply`) for `LivesIn`. That controls the "shape" (if you will) of the pattern constraining the match.

Comment: Unfortunately ```LivesIn(List("Istanbul"))``` does not work for a ```Person``` that has more than one ```Residence``` such as ```Person("Ergin", Seq(Residence("Istanbul", "TR"), Residence("Ankara", "TR"))))```. This is why I'm trying to understand how I can use an extractor such as ```StringSeqContains``` so that it can work for multiple residences.